# Is it possible to add R chain that contains a carbonyl (ketone) to the alpha carbon?

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis

I'm trying to synthesize 2‐(3‐oxobutyl)cyclohexan‐1‐one from cyclohexanone:

[image: 2‐(3‐oxobutyl)cyclohexan‐1‐one]

I thought about LDA, then adding an R group that has a ketone. Is that possible? As far as I know, we can add halogen or alkyl chain only. If it's not possible how can I get this compound from cyclohexanone?

Comment: Consider a Michael reaction with methyl vinyl ketone

Comment: Yes, i figured it sould be conjugate addition! but @Waylander is it possible to add R group that has a ketone as an " alpha carbon alkylation reaction " ?

Comment: Yes it is  https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/jo01031a058. Consider forming the silyl enol ether of the cyclohexanone before introducing the methyl vinyl ketone

Comment: Here is a possible approach  https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja00319a040